# What is the meaning and significance of the phrase "Himmat E Marda toh Madad E Khuda"?

Tags: allah

> Himmat-E-Marda to Madad-E-Khuda

I want to know:

- Where does this phrase come from?
- What is the meaning of it?
- What is the significance of it?

Comment: This quote is neither transliterated Arabic nor English.

Answer (score 3):

It means: *When men dare, God sends help.* Its urdu, possibly also persian. Himmat(همت) means effort, dare, courage etc. Marda(مردا) means men. Madad(مدد) means help, [Khuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khuda) means god.

Its used as an expression, signifying that God helps those who help themselves, or God helps those who put effort.

Answer (score 0):

God helps those who help himself